# Generating an array out of a string seperated by commas and surrounded by parenthesis, in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongoose

**I'm trying to parse a string into an array in Javascript under certain conditions**:

1. Each comma in the string seperates different array elements
2. Elements surrounded by parenthesis are a sub array of the element
   preceding them

Example:

```
total, limit, items(added_at, added_by)
```

will turn into

```
[total, limit, items[added_at, added_by]]
```

**More information on why I'm doing this**:

I'm trying to replicate spotify API's limit fields logic using Mongoose and MongoDB

> to get just the total number of tracks and the request limit:
>   `fields=total,limit`
>
> A dot separator can be used to specify non-reoccurring fields, while parentheses can be used to specify reoccurring fields within objects. For example, to get just the added date and user ID of the adder:
>   `fields=items(added_at,added_by.id)`
>
> Use multiple parentheses to drill down into nested objects, for example:
>   `fields=items(track(name,href,album(name,href)))`

Link: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#endpoint-get-playlists-tracks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it by chunking the string into tokens and stack operators:

```
function parseNestedList(str) {
    let pattern = /([^(),]*)([(),]?)/gm;
    let part, ret = [], stack = [], context = ret;

    while (((part = pattern.exec(str)) !== null) && (part[0].length > 0)) {
        if (part[1].length) { context.push(part[1]); } // Push token

        switch (part[2]) {
            case "(": // Descend
                stack.push(context);
                context.push(context = []);
                break;
            case ",": // Next
                continue;
            default: // Ascend
                context = stack.pop();
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```